# How to disable menus from list of menus per role

Tags: navigation, 9

I'd like to enable visibility per role of menus placed in /admin/structure/menu .
What I want is to allow, for each menu (Administration, development, Footer etc + custom menus), the possibility for a specific role to view them in the list. I don't want a user of an Editor role to be able to modify those menus neither to see all of them, but only a subset.

I tried various modules and hooks, but I still don't manage to do it. It seems that Drupal allows only to set visibility per menu items (links) and not for menus themselves.

Any idea on how to no show some menus in that list per role?